# Element of vector to different columns of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, tidyverse

I have a df:

```
   group number id
1      A   abcd  1
2      A   abcd  2
3      A   abcd  3
4      A   efgh  4
5      A   efgh  5
6      B   abcd  1
7      B   abcd  2
8      B   abcd  3
9      B   abcd  9
10     B   ijkl 10
```

I want to make it like this:

```
   group number  data1 data2 data3 data4           Length
1      A   abcd      1     2     3                      3
2      A   efgh      4     5                            2
3      B   abcd      1     2     3     9                4
4      B   ijkl      10                                 1
```

I am sorry I can only make it to df2 like this:

```
   group number     data               Length
1      A   abcd  c(1,2,3)                   3
2      A   efgh  c(4,5)                     2
3      B   abcd  c(1,2,3,9)                 4
4      B   ijkl  10                         1
```

My code is here:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame (group = c(rep('A',5),rep("B",5)),
                  number = c(rep('abcd',3),rep('efgh',2),rep('abcd',4),rep('ijkl',1)),
                  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,9,10))

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(group,number) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data=map(data,~unlist(.x, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE))，
         Length= map(data, ~length(.x)))
```

Please feel free to start with df or df2, with(out) any package is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must give it to you blindly but that should work or be close :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(group,number) %>%
    mutate(key = paste0("data",row_number()),length = n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    spread(key,id,"")
```

To make it work from your nested data I think you have to change these vectors into 1 line data.frames of same col numbers and names , then use unnest, much more complicated! :)

Comment: This seems the clearest answer. I think you can avoid the `ungroup`, and If you put an extra var in `mutate` you can get the length variable in the output too - `df %>% group_by(group,number) %>% mutate(rn=paste0("data",row_number()),length=n()) %>% spread(rn, id)` for instance.

Comment: Yes I hadn't seen the last col thanks :). You can skip the ungroup and it prints fine but then you forget it's grouped and you mess it up when you rework your table later :).

Answer (score 4):

You can change the name `count` to `length`(also, I perfer make the 'space' to `NA`, If want to change it , `df2[is.na(df2)]=''`)

---

Option 1

```
df <- data.frame (group = c(rep('A',5),rep("B",5)),
                  number = c(rep('abcd',3),rep('efgh',2),rep('abcd',4),rep('ijkl',1)),
                  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,9,10))

df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(group,number) %>%
    mutate(data=toString(id),count=n())

library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df2, 3, drop = TRUE,sep=',')


   group number count data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4
1:     A   abcd     3      1      2      3     NA
2:     A   efgh     2      4      5     NA     NA
3:     B   abcd     4      1      2      3      9
4:     B   ijkl     1     10     NA     NA     NA
```

---

Option 2

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
     group_by(group,number) %>%
     summarise(data=toString(id),count=n())%>%separate_rows(data)%>% mutate(Col = paste0("data", 1:n()))%>%spread(Col, data)
df2
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   group [2]
   group number count data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
* <fctr> <fctr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      A   abcd     3     1     2     3  <NA>  <NA>
2      A   efgh     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     4     5
3      B   abcd     4     1     2     3     9  <NA>
4      B   ijkl     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    10
```

Comment: This seems rather more fragile than @moody's answer below. For instance, consider that `toString(c("1,","2","3"))` with an embedded `,` returns `"1,, 2, 3"`

Comment: @thelatemail in that condition his answer is better , For my answer I start with the original data input..;-)

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
temp = split(df, paste(df$group, df$number))
columns = max(sapply(temp, NROW))
do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(a)
    cbind(group = a$group[1],
          number = a$number[1],
          setNames(data.frame(t(a$id[1:columns])), paste0("data", 1:columns)),
          length = length(a$id))
))
#       group number data1 data2 data3 data4 length
#A abcd     A   abcd     1     2     3    NA      3
#A efgh     A   efgh     4     5    NA    NA      2
#B abcd     B   abcd     1     2     3     9      4
#B ijkl     B   ijkl    10    NA    NA    NA      1
```

Comment: You could also adapt from what @moody_mudskipper did in dplyr and use `reshape` in base R - `ids <- c("group","number"); reshape(transform(df, time=ave(rep(1,nrow(df)), df[ids], FUN=seq_along)), idvar=ids, direction="wide", sep="")` or similar

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), group + number~ paste0("data", rowid(group, number)), 
 value.var = 'id', fill = 0)[, 
   length := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `>`, 0)), .SDcols = data1:data4][]
#    group number data1 data2 data3 data4 length
#1:     A   abcd     1     2     3     0      3
#2:     A   efgh     4     5     0     0      2
#3:     B   abcd     1     2     3     9      4
#4:     B   ijkl    10     0     0     0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of [akrun's `data.table` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231257/3817004) which does compute `Length` *before* reshaping from long to wide format and uses the `prefix` parameter in the call to `rowid()`:

```
library(data.table)

data.table(df)[, Length := .N, by = .(group, number)][
  , dcast(.SD, group + number + Length ~ rowid(group, number, prefix = "data"), 
          value.var = "id")]
```

> ```
>    group number Length data1 data2 data3 data4
> 1:     A   abcd      3     1     2     3    NA
> 2:     A   efgh      2     4     5    NA    NA
> 3:     B   abcd      4     1     2     3     9
> 4:     B   ijkl      1    10    NA    NA    NA
> ```

For pretty printing, the `NA` values can be converted into white space:

```
data.table(df)[, Length := .N, by = .(group, number)][
  , dcast(.SD, group + number + Length ~ rowid(group, number, prefix = "data"), 
          as.character, value.var = "id", fill = "")]
```

> ```
>    group number Length data1 data2 data3 data4
> 1:     A   abcd      3     1     2     3      
> 2:     A   efgh      2     4     5            
> 3:     B   abcd      4     1     2     3     9
> 4:     B   ijkl      1    10
> ```